# HOW to CONVERT Touch Input To Mouse Input C# unity?

Tags: c#, input, touch, mouse

i want to play my Unity Game in Mouse Input mode too (my Script now is Touch Input), can everyone help me to convert my script to Mouse input?? 
using if unity_editor , endif:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

//some code for mouse input

#endif
```

my script in here : http://pastebin.com/HJwbEzy4

thanks you so much who help me!! :)

or here :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Main_Menu_02 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject InstructionContainer;
    public GameObject Buttons;
    public GameObject AW;
    public GameObject Instruction;
    public GameObject Exit;
    public Texture Active;
    public Texture nonActive;



    public AudioClip SFX_select;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.touches.Length <=0)
        {
            this.guiTexture.texture = nonActive;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Input.touches.Length == 1)
            {
                if(this.guiTexture.HitTest(Input.GetTouch(0).position))
                {
                    if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                    {
                        audio.PlayOneShot(SFX_select);
                        this.guiTexture.texture = Active;
                    }
                    if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    {
                        if(this.gameObject == AW)
                            Application.LoadLevel("LoadingAW");
                        else if(this.gameObject == Instruction)
                        {
                            InstructionContainer.SetActive(true);
                            Buttons.SetActive(false);
                        }
                        else if (this.gameObject == Exit)
                        {
                            Application.Quit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need of touches. You can use `Input.GetMouseButton`, will work on both.

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` for touch begin.

`Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` for touch ended.

`Input.GetMouseButton(0)` for touch begin and move.

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        print("Touch begin");
    // So on....
```

}